# How can I optimize my AIR iOS app for iphone 5, working with Flash

Tags: iphone, ios, air, fullscreen

I've released an app for android & iOS, using AIR and developed with Flash CS6.

It works on iPhone and iPad but I can't get it to use the whole screen on retina screen devices.

- The app is built to use the maximum space based on Capabilities.screenResolutionX & Capabilities.screenResolutionY
- The resolution is set to High in the descriptor file (and in flash)
- I tried to add startup screens (Default.png,Default@2x.png,Default-568&2x.png) but that last one is never used.
- I tried to use the Fullscreen option but as expected it only removes the menubar (and I'd like to keep that)

Any idea?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that, I found the answer on my own.

It is indeed the Startup screen that tells iOs if an app should be displayed in high resolution (rather than the descriptor) so I was quite right and it's good to know.

My problem was I named it Default-568@2x.png instead of Default-568h@2x.png.

Found the typo, changed it and it works!

Comment: Hi Antoine, can you please give an example of what you did. I don't know what you mean a "default" image? Like do I put it on the screen and name it that is a MovieClip - Should the image itself as it is imported in the assests ben be called Default-568h@2x.png? Please explain, if you could, what you did to get it to work. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, the default images have to be put in the same folder as the descriptive file and the compiled app. No need to include or import them in the fla. They just have to be in the folder.
Non exhaustive list from  my last project :
Default-568h@2x.png
Default-Portrait.png
Default-Portrait@2x.png
Default.png
Default@2x.png

Comment: Sorry but I still don't know where that is. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you using Flash IDE ou Flash builder? In any case, when you publish your app (compile it) it's in a folder (default is the same as fla). This is the folder I'm talking about.

Comment: I am using Flash Professional. So lets say for example I have a folder called "myApp" and in the folder I have myApp.fla are you saying all I have to do is put these files in that folder? Default-568h@2x.png Default-Portrait.png Default-Portrait@2x.png Default.png Default@2x.png and Flash will automatically upload them? Also, so I am assuming I have to have "Real" PNG files right? If so what are the exact dimensions for them?  - Someone should do a real clear tutorial about this. I am sure many google it. :)

Comment: You can actually find a few infos on [Adobe website](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/publishing-air-android-applications.html) for starters.
And this one regarding Launch images: [Default images dimensions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html)